# Torrc statistics options

Tags: configuration

The Tor manual contains a range of statistics options such as CellStatistics,  DirReqStatistics, and  ExitPortStatistics.
In the description of these options it says:

> Tor writes statistics on ... to disk every 24 hours.

Where on disk does it write to? Are the files configurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the Manual Page you will find a [Files Section](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual-dev.html.en#_files) containing the various files Tor uses. Most of use `DataDirectory` which can be configured via an option of the same name like `DataDirectory /some/path`.